# How to encrypt web.config section AND deploy to multiple servers with Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, web-config, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a website using AWS Elastic Beanstalk and it is very easy to deploy into a load balanced web farm.

Now, I want to encrypt some of the sections in the web.config for the sites that I have deployed, whether it is before deploying, or after.

There are many articles on how to use the Aspnet_regiis.exe tool using RSA to encrypt a section, however, the issue is when you are dealing with a web farm because you need to export the private key to other servers.

From this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx see:

> **Web Farm Scenarios** If you want to deploy the same encrypted configuration file on multiple servers in a Web farm, you should use
>   the RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider. This provider makes it easy for
>   you encrypt the data on one server computer and then export the RSA
>   private key needed to decrypt the data. You can then deploy the
>   configuration file and the exported key to the target servers, and
>   then re-import the keys.

However, my problem is that in a load balanced environment, servers are going to go up and down due to Autoscale rules, and I need a process to automate the management of the keys, that is, importing on a newly deployed server the private keys used to encrypt the Web.config.

Has anyone done this or can provide some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you leverage container commands to import private keys? The command will be executed each time the instance is initialized. Once you begin keeping your keys in a persistent store, S3, for example, then autoscaling should not be an issue.

[Customizing the Software on EC2 Instances Running Windows](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-windows-ec2.html) has more details on container commands.

Answer (score 5):

Following @kukido 's suggestion what you need to do is create an .ebextension file with the following content.

```
commands:
  encryptConfig:
    command: aspnet_regiis.exe -pe "connectionStrings" -app /
    cwd: %windir%\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319
```